# ShareX image uploading gives 403 forbidden on new Apache Server

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have figured out the base of the problem, but I have no idea how to fix it. I have a user configured named files, which has write permissions to /var/www/html/files/ and can write and read fine to it. However, when uploading a file, my apache server gets a 403 forbidden error upon viewing it. To fix it, I have to SSH into my server and chown the directory to the www-data user to see the file. Obviously, I don't want to do this every time I upload an image, since this is very frequently. How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a group and adding www-data to it, then grant write privileges for the folder to the group (775 or something similar)?